# Access VBA Error 3075

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I am Running Access 2016 and I am trying to get some records from a query. I am an Access noob and I am making a database. 
When I run the following Code, i get Error 3075, and it says an Operator is not there, the thing is, when i paste the SQL code into an access Query it runs just fine, so I cant see the problem

```
    Sub DOthings()

Dim i As Integer
Dim array1() As Variant
Dim array2() As Variant

Dim daDb As DAO.Database
Set daDb = CurrentDb


'' getting temp vars first
Dim vend As String
vend = CStr([TempVars]![temp1]) '' I get these TEMP vars from the access application

Dim loc As String
loc = CStr([TempVars]![temp2])

MsgBox ("Vendor is: " & vend & " And Location is: " & loc)
'setting SQL statement
Dim qry As String 'SQL STATEMENT FOR QUERY
qry = "SELECT [Table1].ScanID, [Table2].FieldV, [Table1].[FieldA], [Table1].[FieldE], (([Table1]![FieldE])/([Table1]![FieldA])) AS V, [Table1].[QR Code], [Table3].[Selected?], [Table3].[Location Recieved], [Table3].[Travel Notes] FROM ([Table2] INNER JOIN [Table1] ON [Table2].BatchID = [Table1].BatchID) INNER JOIN [Table3] ON [Table1].ScanID = [Table3].Scan_ID **WHERE ((([Table2].FieldV) = " & vend & ") And (([Table3].[Location Recieved]) = " & loc & ") And (([Table3].[Date Shipped]) Is Null)) ORDER BY (([Table1]![fieldE])/([Table1]![FieldA])) DESC;**"
Dim daQdf As DAO.QueryDef 'First Query to find and SELECT the actual datapoints."
Set daQdf = daDb.CreateQueryDef(qname, qry)

Dim daRs As DAO.Recordset 'Getting the recordset Setup
Set daRs = daQdf.OpenRecordset(qname, Dynaset)
```

So The error I am getting basically says my Where statement is wrong, but i cant see the problem. Is the source of the error somewhere else?

This is the Error statement i am getting:

[image]

Can Anyone Tell me how I can fix this? Or what the cause of the Problem is?

Comment: when passing a `string` variable into an SQL statement in VBA single quotes `'` need to surround the text. So  `= " & vend & ")` becomes  = `'" & vend & "')`

Comment: Thanks! That Solves that error. Now I have a different Albeit unrelated one! I appreciate the Help Scott.